# Why my img is not loaded in my page html?

Tags: html, css

The first image load right but the second is not showed?

```
<p>Insert an image from a random web site:</p>
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/lamp.jpg" alt="Lamp" width="32" height="32">
<img src="http://www.eventoscasua.com/GranjaCasua/images/arepas.jpg" width="32" height="32">
```

Comment: why did you tag the question css ? Where is the css part ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think non-source (http) url

```html
<p>Insert an image from a random web site:</p>
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/lamp.jpg" alt="Lamp" width="32" height="32">
<img src="http://www.eventoscasua.com/granjacasua/images/arepas.jpg" width="32" height="32">
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have the permission to use the image (try using other images from the same website and see if the image shows up). Additionally, you can add the  'alt' attribute (add simple text in it like the first image) to show whether the image is actually there or not.